# How can I test a method and to mock another method that are in the same class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, unit-testing, dart, mockito

**Description:**
I have already tested `methodA()` and `methodB()` so I can be sure that they are covered.
What are the ways to test `methodToBeTested()` by mocking `methodA()` and `methodB()` that are in the same file? The parameters are passed through the `methodToBeTested()` to the `methodA()` and `methodB()` to properly test these methods using injection.
Note: They are cannot be extracted to a different class since it is a related logic of the calculation service and these methods are already atomically is separated.

**Code:**

```
class ClassForTesting {
  int methodToBeTested(String a, String b) {
     // Calculation in this method also is a bit more difficult
     return methodA() + methodB();
  } 

  int methodA(String a) {
     int value = 1;
     // Here is calculation logic that has been tested
     return value;
  } 

  int methodB(String b) {
     int value = 2;
     // Here is calculation logic that has been tested
     return value;
  } 
}
```

**What has been done:**
I have tried several approaches from Mockito, but it doesn't allow to do such a trick:

1. `@GenerateMocks` - is creating a mock and requires me to stub each method using `when()`, even `methodToBeTested()`.
2. By extending Fake using the next construction:

```dart
class Mock extends Fake implements PasswordValidatorService {}
```

But in this way, I'm only inheriting the `PasswordValidatorService's` behavior instead of instead implementation and each non-overridden method throws `UnimplementedError`. Thus, I'm not able to override `methodToBeTested()` and call its super implementation.

I found that Mockito for Java has `@Spy` construction that would be perfect in this case but unfortunately it is not available for Dart and Flutter.

The only way I currently came is to create my own Mock:

```
class MockClassForTesting extends ClassForTesting {
  @override
  int methodA() {
    return 2;
  }

  @override
  int methodB() {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

But this implementation doesn't allow me to use Mockito's flexibility of `when()` construction since I must have different `methodA()` and `methodB()` returns.
This fact forces me to have additional variables in my `MockClassForTesting` to achieve `when()` construction functionality.

**The questions:**

1. What would be the best way to achieve my purposes?
2. Can be the same mocking approach to be used during the Widget testing?

Comment: You could make your own derived class with overrides for `methodA` and `methodB` and have those specific overrides delegate to a `Mock` implementation.

Comment: @jamesdlin The first part is already done and described in the question, but the second one I do not undestand since. This is very first day I'm doing unit tests in Flutter. Do you mean to use GenerateMocks for the MockClassForTesting?

Comment: I mean doing both things: create your own derived class and create a `Mock` as you normally would, but then use a hybrid approach where your derived class uses the `Mock` for specific methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a hybrid approach where you create your own derived class but where some of its overrides delegate to a `Mock` implementation.  For example:

```dart
class ClassForTesting {
  int methodToBeTested(String a, String b) {
     // Calculation in this method also is a bit more difficult
     return methodA(a) + methodB(b);
  } 

  int methodA(String a) {
     int value = 1;
     // Here is calculation logic that has been tested
     return value;
  } 

  int methodB(String b) {
     int value = 2;
     // Here is calculation logic that has been tested
     return value;
  } 
}

class PartialMockClassForTesting extends ClassForTesting {
  final mock = MockClassForTesting();

  @override
  int methodA(String a) => mock.methodA(a);

  @override
  int methodB(String b) => mock.methodB(b);
}

@GenerateMocks([ClassForTesting])
void main() {
  test('Test partial mock', () {
    var partialMock = PartialMockClassForTesting();
    when(partialMock.methodA('hello')).thenReturn(42);
    when(partialMock.methodA('goodbye')).thenReturn(-42);
    when(partialMock.methodB('world')).thenReturn(10);

    expect(partialMock.methodToBeTested('hello', 'world'), 52);
    expect(partialMock.methodToBeTested('goodbye', 'world'), -32);
  });
}
```

If you want to conditionally mock certain methods, you could have your overrides check boolean flags to conditionally call either the mock or the real implementation.  For example:

```dart
class PartialMockClassForTesting extends ClassForTesting {
  final mock = MockClassForTesting();
  final shouldMock = <Function, bool>{};

  @override
  int methodA(String a) =>
      shouldMock[methodA] ?? false ? mock.methodA(a) : super.methodA(a);

  @override
  int methodB(String b) =>
      shouldMock[methodB] ?? false ? mock.methodB(b) : super.methodB(b);
}

@GenerateMocks([ClassForTesting])
void main() {
  test('Test partial mock', () {
    var partialMock = PartialMockClassForTesting();
    partialMock.shouldMock[partialMock.methodA] = true;
    partialMock.shouldMock[partialMock.methodB] = true;
    ...
```

Comment: This is a very good answer but in this way I cannot pass any matchers to methodA as a parameter. Do you have any idea how make this possible?

Comment: @DenFav You can always do `partialMock.mock.methodA(argumentMatcher)` if you need to, or you could make `PartialMock`'s overrides use parameters of `dynamic` type.

Comment: Thanks it worked. One more question as to this.  
The class contais methods methodToBeTested, A, B, C. methodToBeTested calls A and B, B calls C.
By mocking A and B I can test methodToBeTested, but if I mock C, I cannot test B, since B is mocked and needs stub on except function. I tried to stub the B to call real implementation, but I'm not able to call parent implementaion of the method in thenAnswer closure. Is there any way to do this or I need to create another custom mock class? Thanks!

Comment: @DenFav I've updated my answer with an approach that should be less work than creating a custom class for each combination of methods that you want to mock.